# Is there a desktop application for launchpad.net?

Tags: software-recommendation, launchpad

I was looking at the Launchpad.net and came to this page (see the screenshot below). I started wondering if there are any desktop applications for using Launchpad.net without the necessity of a web browser.

[image]

Are there any?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is commonly used for a number of command-line tools, such as those in the ubuntu-dev-tools package,

There is also a desktop client called [Ground Control](http://ground-control.org/) [image: install ground control]. which mostly focuses on bugs & branches.

Also under development is a [Unity Lens](http://launchpad.net/unity-lens-launchpad/) which currently can search people, packages & bugs by number. This doesn't use the Launchpad credentials in the screenshot, but the anonymous access.

Comment: That lens looks interesting, but it has only 9 bzr revisions and no packages for download yet. Do you know how stable/usable it is if you compile it from source at this point?

Comment: It's not overly usable, but is in https://launchpad.net/~ajmitch/+archive/unity-lenses if you feel like trying it out. I haven't spent much time working on it lately though.

Answer (score 6):

There is a [list of programs](https://help.launchpad.net/API/Uses) that use the Launchpad API.

It contains desktop applications (eg. [Bughugger](http://www.murraytwins.com/blog/?p=60)), but I could not find a mention for a full-blown desktop client.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know there was an actual list maintained. And as it says, any of those programs could serve as examples to help others learn to write more.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. It's called [Ground Control](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/groundcontrol) [image: install ground control].